# Lamar un formulario hermano en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy tratando de abrir un formulario que desde uno que es hijo, la cosa es que necesito que quede siendo hijo de un componente del principal.
Me explico: tengo un panel en el formulario padre en el cual tengo como contenedor de los formularios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito llamar desde este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este otro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y que quede siendo hijo del panel que se encuentra en el padre.

Estuve intentando con este código:

Botón buscar cliente en el hijo 1:

```
Inicio padre = new Inicio();
padre = (Inicio)this.Owner;
padre.btncliseach_Click(sender, e);
```

Función en botón oculto en el formulario padre:

```
Inicio padre = new Inicio();
CliSeach Fom = new CliSeach();
Fom.TopLevel = false;
Fom.AutoScroll = true;
this.Contenedor.Controls.Add(Fom);
this.Contenedor.Tag = Fom;
Fom.Show();
```

Y también con este otro:

Botón buscar cliente en el hijo 1:

```
CliSeach buscar = new CliSeach();
Mifuncion.llamarhijo(buscar);
```

Función aparte:

```
Inicio padre = new Inicio();
Form fom = new Form();
fom.TopLevel = false;
fom.AutoScroll = true;
padre.Contenedor.Controls.Add(fom);
padre.Contenedor.Tag = fom;
fom.Show();
```

El primero me da error y el segundo no hace nada, llevo mas de una semana estancado y no se me ocurre nada mas que hacer con esto.

Comment: En este sitio hay varias respuestas si en el buscador usas la frase ['*entre formularios*'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=entre+formularios) con varias respuestas útiles. Cuál de ellas no se ajusta a tu problema?

Comment: a que te referis con hijo? cual seria la finalidad, no te comprendi

Comment: @RamiroBarone uno que depende de **X** formulario u objeto en un formulario para existir o su correcto funcionamiento;
su finalidad (en mi caso) seria controlar la cantidad de formularios abiertos